# Jetpack Compose - Swipe interaction on HorizontalPager not working after BoM update

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, horizontal-pager

I recently updated my `compose-BoM` version from 2023.06.01 to 2023.08.00 (and later 2023.10.00) and also updated the `navigation-compose` dependency (which is not included in the BoM) from 2.6.* to 2.7.1 (later 2.7.4).

With 2023.06.01 / 2.6.* my `HorizontalPager` worked perfectly. Since the update it does not. When I swipe to change the page, or when I change the page programatically by calling `pagerState.animateScrollToPage(int)`, the page does not visibly change. When I check the `pagerState`'s `currentPage` value, that has changed to the correct page.

As opposed to the examples in the official docs, the amount of pages can change dynamically in my situation.

Here's the code (simplified):

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun <T> MyPager(items: List<T>) {
    
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        initialPage = 0,
        initialPageOffsetFraction = 0f,
        pageCount = { 
            Log.i(TAG, "pageCount called")
            items.size 
        }
    )

    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        pageSpacing = -50.dp // Makes edge of next/prev page visible
    ) { pageIndex ->
        
        val item = items.getOrNull(index) ?: return@HorizontalPager
        
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Text("Item at page $pageIndex")
            // Show other things for `item` here
        }
    }
}

------

@Composable
fun MyScreen(viewModel: MyViewModel) {

    val items = viewModel.itemList.collectAsState() //itemList is of type Flow<List<MyItem>>

    MyPager(items)
}
```

When the list of `items` contains multiple items, I can see the next page due to the `pageSpacing` I set, but when I swipe, the screen does not respond. I do see the log statement in `pagerState.pageCount` is called with the correct number of pages.

With the previous versions of the Compose BoM and navigation library, where the `pageCount` was passed directly to the `HorizontalPager`, I did not have this issue.

Who can help me get my pager working again?

Comment: Worked for me with `bom:2023.10.00`, except with a local static `items` list.

Comment: @JanItor When I use a static list it works for me as well. But in my case the list is dynamic (scan results of a BLE scan)